# I try to put a Favicon in an Inertiajs app but it doesn't work

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, laravel-9, favicon, inertiajs

I'm trying to add the favicon to a Inertiajs app but it doesnt work.

I'm using laravel 9 with inertiajs, vue3 with vite and tailwind.

The route is fine "Public/Images"

Do any one understand why?

```
<link rel="icon" type="svg+xml" sizes="32x32" href="../../public/Images/Favicon.svg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

laravel web folder is at `public` so all you need to do is reference it as the TLD,

in your `resources/views/app.blade.php`

you can directly reference a directory inside public, so instead of `../../public/Images/Favicon.svg` it should be `/Images/Favicon.svg`

```
<link rel="icon" href="/Images/Favicon.svg" />
```